# custom action for devise registrations controller getting nil resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

basically I want to have two separate actions for change password and change email instead of just one.

I have updated my routes to point to my new controller which inherits from Devise::RegistrationsController.

My routes.rb:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }

devise_scope :user do
  get "/users/password" => "registrations#change_password", :as => :change_password
end
```

My registrations_controller.rb

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def change_password
  end

end
```

My app/views/devise/registrations/change_password.html.erb

```
<%=debug resource%>
```

Which gives me nil.

What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

In Devise's built-in [registrations_controller.rb](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb), there is an `authenticate_scope!` method that creates the `resource` object you're looking for. It is executed by a `prepend_before_filter`, but only for certain methods:

```
class Devise::RegistrationsController < DeviseController
  ...
  prepend_before_filter :authenticate_scope!, :only => [:edit, :update, :destroy]`
```

So you simply need to tell your custom controller to run that filter on your `change_password` method:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  prepend_before_filter :authenticate_scope!, :only => [:change_password]

  def change_password
  end

end
```

Comment: i guess you'll need to append `:change_password` action to those default `[:edit, :update, :destroy]` instead of specifying only `:change_password`. in my similar case, i have action called `:finish`, and if i specify `only: :finish`, then `resource` is `nil` for `edit` action

Answer (score -3):

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def change_password
    super
    @resource = resource
  end
end
```

app/views/devise/registrations/change_password.html.erb

```
<%=debug @resource%>
```

Comment: I tested this and it didn't work for me because the `Devise::RegistrationsController` superclass has no `change_password` method for the `super` keyword to reference.